# How do I replace a string when altering the output of a view field?

Tags: views, 8

I have some text I'd like to alter in the custom output of a view field.  For example, if the output contains *pancakes*, I'd like to replace it with *waffles*.

The following code doesn't work.

```
{{ field_recipe_prep__value | replace({'pancakes': "waffles"}) }}
```

How do I replace a string when altering the output of a view field?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `__value` part.

```
{{ field_recipe_prep | replace({'pancakes': "waffles"}) }}
```